# How can I extract the ROI from mammogram image without using the im2bw function

Tags: matlab

When using Matlab code for ROI extraction from mammography image (unit8) must be convert to a binary image. I need help to extract ROI without using convert function.

I'm using this code

```
org = imread('mdb.pgm');
org = im2bw(org);
ext = org(any(org,2),:);
ext = ext(:,any(org,1));
```

Comment: Could you supply a sample image and point out (e.g by drawing manually) where your ROI is and describe a bit more what you are actually trying to extract?

Comment: my project is about breast cancer detection using genetic algorithm (for optimization ) and neural network (for classification) >>> 
so am try to extract the brightness area from mammogram image